# How do I make a Gui in python?

Tags: python, user-interface

Alright so I am not big brain. Can someone give me a tutorial or recommend one? I've heard tkinter is good, so maybe use that? I don't know please help me.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These two documents will help others answer your question quicker.

Answer (score 1):

See [GuiProgramming](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) in the official wiki which shows a HUGE amount of frameworks in categories such as:

- cross-browser
- cross-platform
- platform-specific

and other from which most of the known ones I'd say are [PyJamas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyjs), [PyGame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyGame), [PyQt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt), [Kivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kivy_(framework)), [Tkinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) and [wxPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wxPython)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GhzpvvIXlM

It is a simple tutorial that explains how to make a GUI. It uses Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tkinter or Guizero to create GUIs using Python